# Birthday attack/problem, calculate exact numbers?

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Birthday-coverage problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26772/birthday-coverage-problem)

An example of what I wish to do is the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681913/substr-md5-collision/4785456#4785456

How would I calculate how many people would be required, as in the link above, to reach 50% or 0.001% or *n*% probability of collision exactly?

I am able to calculate the likelyhood of a collision in say a hash, with

$1-e^\frac{-n^2}{(2*10^6)}$

10^6 being six numerical digits from zero to nine. However, I would have to guess a lot of times before I got the exact number of people it would take to reach exactly 50%, which may be a fraction (i.e. 20.2 people)

How would I be able to find this?

Comment: Are you assuming that birthdates are uniformly-distributed? There is data that leads to reasonably questioning this belief/assumption.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26772/birthday-coverage-problem), where exact calculations, very tight approximations, hard bounds, and the expected value can all be found in the various answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused by the question because it contains the word "exact" four times but you suggest to calculate the probability of a collision using a relatively simple approximation. For this answer, I'll assume that you're aware that there are [better approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations) for this probability, and of the various answers you get by searching for "birthday" on this site, and that your question is only about calculating $n$ given $1-\exp(-n^2/(2k))$. This you can do by solving for $n$ as follows:

$$
p=1-\mathrm e^{-n^2/2k}\;,
$$
$$
\mathrm e^{-n^2/2k}=1-p\;,
$$
$$
-\frac{n^2}{2k}=\log(1-p)\;,
$$
$$
n^2=-2k\log(1-p)\;,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
n&=&\sqrt{-2k\log(1-p)}\\
&=&\sqrt{2k\log\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where $\log$ is the natural logarithm, i. e. the logarithm to base $\mathrm e$.

Comment: The ln function is great, I never thought it could be this easy. Thank you for your steps.

Comment: It seems to me that the last equation omits the - before 2k.

Comment: @Ceki is right. There should indeed be a minus sign before the $2k$ (or the $1 - p$ be $\frac{1}{1 - p}$ instead). Here's a query in Wolfram|Alpha: [solve p = 1 - e^-(x^2 / (2 k)) over the reals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+p+%3D+1+-+e%5E-%28x%5E2+%2F+%282+k%29%29+over+the+reals)

Comment: *Update:* I decided to edit instead the above post.

Comment: @JasonSparc: Thanks for the correction!