# The Birthday Paradox - Inverted

Tags: combinatorics, birthday

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Birthday-coverage problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26772/birthday-coverage-problem)

How many people in a group do you need to have a better-than-even chance that all 365 (or 366) birthdays of the year are represented?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26772/birthday-coverage-problem/26777#26777

Comment: @Byron: Yes, it is. Thanks!