# Tail bound on the sum of independent (non-identical) geometric random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1, \ldots , X_k$ are $k$ independent geometric random variables with success probability $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ and let $X = X_1 + \cdots + X_k$.

The expected number of trials needed is 
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \frac{1}{p_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{p_k} \> .
$$

**Claim**:  It should be true that there is a constant $c>0$ (independent of $k$ and the success probabilities $p_i$) such that for any $t>0$ we have
 $$
\mathbb P[X > c (\mathbb E[X] + t)] < (1 - p_\min)^t \>,
$$
where $p_\min = \min_i p_i$.

I would be very thankful for any help in proving this.

Note that if $p_1 = \cdots = p_k = p$ then $X$ is a negative binomial random variable. In this case, one can prove the claim with $c=16$ via a standard Chernoff bound: The expected number of successes after $16(\frac{k}{p}+t)$ trials is $16(k+tp)$ and, by the Chernoff bound, the probability that there are less than $k<\frac{1}{2}E[X]$ successes is at most $e^{-16(k+tp)/8}$ which is less than $e^{-2tp} < (1 - p)^t$.

Comment: To help with intuition of the claim: $X_i$ is the number of tosses we have to make with coin $i$ (with success probability $p_i$) to get the first success and $X$ is the total number of trials needed to get one success with each of $k$ different coins. The claim then states that the probability that one needs more than ($c$ times) the expected number of trials plus $t$ extra ones gets exponentially smaller with $t$ and is essentially as unlikely as having thrown the worst coin $t$ times without getting one success.

Comment: I've merged your two accounts. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $0 < p_1 \leq p_2 \leq \cdots \leq p_k$ and $X = X_1 + \cdots + X_k$ where $X_i$ are independent geometric random variables with parameter $p_i$. Let $\mu = \mathbb E X = \sum_{m=1}^k \frac{1}{p_m}$.

Below, we show a considerably stronger result than that claimed in the question. In particular:

**Claim**: For any $c \geq 2$ and any $k$, we have
$$\renewcommand{\Pr}{\mathbb P}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}
\Pr(X > c (\mu + t) ) \leq (1-p_1)^t \exp(-(2c-3)k/4) \>.
$$

*Proof*: By Markov's inequality applied to $e^{s X}$, for any $s > 0$,
$$
\Pr(X > c (\mu + t) ) \leq e^{-s c t} e^{-s c \mu} \prod_{m=1}^k \E e^{s X_m} \>.
$$

It is an easy exercise to check that
$$
\E e^{s X_m} = \frac{p_m e^s}{1-(1-p_m) e^s} = \Big(1-\frac{1-e^{-s}}{p_m}\Big)^{-1}
$$

Let $s = -\frac{1}{c}\log(1-p_1)$ so that $e^{-sc} = (1-p_1)$. Then, we get that
$$
\Pr(X > c (\mu + t) ) \leq (1-p_1)^t \exp( a \mu - {\textstyle\sum_{m=1}^k} \log(1-b/p_m)) \>,
$$
where $a = \log(1-p_1)$ and $b = 1-(1-p_1)^{1/c}$.

Recalling the definition of $\mu$ and concentrating on the exponent of the last term, we need to find some $c$ such that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^k \frac{a}{b}\frac{b}{p_m} - \log(1 - b/p_m) < 0 \>.
$$
Letting $c \geq 2$ and using [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), we have $b = 1-(1-p_1)^{1/c} \leq p_1/c \leq p_1 / 2$ and so, in particular $b/p_m \leq 1/2$ for all $m$.

Since, for $0 < z \leq 1/2$, the inequality $\log(1-z) \geq -z - z^2$ holds, we get that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^k \frac{a}{b}\frac{b}{p_m} - \log(1 - b/p_m) \leq \frac{k}{2} (\frac{a}{b} + \frac{3}{2}) \>.
$$

But, $a = \log(1-p_1) < 0$ and $b \leq p_1 / c$, so
$$
\frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{c\log(1-p_1)}{p_1} \leq -c \>.
$$

Putting everything together, we have shown that
$$
\Pr(X > c (\mu + t) ) \leq (1-p_1)^t \exp(-(2c-3)k/4)
$$
as claimed.

---

**Notes**: We observe the following:

1. We can take $c = 2$ even in the case that $p = p_m > 0$ for all $m$.
2. The special case where $p_m = m/k$ corresponds to the [coupon collector problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). There are some sharper asymptotics in the case of the former problem as well as [upper and lower bounds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/).
3. Coupon collecting is also related to the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). For more on this connection, here's an [interesting question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26772) with several different answers.

Comment: Great and detailed answer. Thanks, cardinal!

Comment: I think Bernoulli's inequality is being used incorrectly here. For $0 \leq x \leq 1 $ we have $(1-p)^x \leq 1-px$ so $px \leq 1-(1-p)^x$.

Comment: The main claim is wrong.  Suppose $p_1=1/(k-1)$ and $p_2 = p_k = 1$.  Then $\mu = 1/p_1 + (k-1) = 2/p_1$.  To be concrete take $c=2$.  The claimed bound implies
$P(X_1 \geq 3/p_1) \leq \exp(-k/4)$.
The LHS is constant while the RHS is exponentially small.
(Note: my student Saeed came up with this but his reputation is too low to comment.)

Answer (score 0):

A coupling argument works nicely nicely here. Let $X_1'$, $\cdots$, $X_k'$ be $k$ independent geometric random variables of parameter $p_{\min}$. Then we can couple the random variable $X_i$ and $X_i'$ in such a way that $X_i \leq X_i'$ because $p_{\min}$ is, well, $p_{\min}$. I can also choose all these couplings to be independent, which gives be a coupling between $(X_i)$ and $(X_i')$. This coupling in turn gives a coupling between $X$ and $X' = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i'$ such that $X \leq X'$.

By your argument (which I didn't check), we know that:

$$\mathbb{P} (X' \geq 16 (\mathbb{E} (X')+t)) \leq (1-p_{\min})^t.$$

Since $X \leq X'$, we have:

$$\mathbb{P} \left(X \geq 16 \frac{\mathbb{E} (X')}{\mathbb{E} (X)} \left(\mathbb{E} (X)+t\right)\right) \leq \mathbb{P} \left(X \geq 16 \left(\frac{\mathbb{E} (X')}{\mathbb{E} (X)}\mathbb{E} (X)+t\right)\right) \leq (1-p_{\min})^t.$$

Then we can replace $\mathbb{E} (X')/\mathbb{E} (X)$ by its exact value.

This argument is not very involved, and there should be a way to get better constants, however.

Comment: Thanks, D.Thomine. Unfortunately in your solution we get $c = 16\frac{E(X')}{E(X)}$ which makes the constant $c$ depend on $k$ and the success probabilities $p_i$. I added a clarifying sentence to the question.

Answer (score 0):

With $c\ge 2$, $0<r=1/c <1$; with $x=-p_1 \ge -1$ applying Bernoulli's inequality we actually obtain $b=1−(1−p_1)^{1/c}\ge p_1/c$.