# How can I solve bins-and-balls problems?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins, birthday

Below is the problem that I wanted to solve

> When there are $m$ balls and $n$ bins, balls are thrown into  bins where each ball is thrown into a bin uniformly at random. What is the expected number of bins that contain strictly more than 1 ball?

What I am understanding so far is that, each ball toss will be independent, and expected number of balls in each basket will be $m/n$. But this does not seem to help me solving the problem.

I heard this is very similar to the birthday problem, but with different number of bins and arbitrary number of balls.

How should I approach solving this problem?

Answer (score 10):

When trying to find the expectation of a "complicated" random variable, you can try using the very useful technique of writing the complicated variable as a sum of simpler variables and using the fact that the expectation of a sum of random variables is the sum of the individual  expectations (note this is true of any sum, independence is not needed).

Here, for each $i=1$, $2$, $\ldots\,$, $n$, define the random variable
$$X_i=\cases{1,& if the $i^{\rm th}$ bin contains 2 or more balls,\cr0,&otherwise.}$$

Now let $X$ be the  total number of bins that contain two or more balls. Note that 
$X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Using the linearity of expectation:
$$
\Bbb E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n \Bbb E(X_i).
$$

Note each $X_i$ is a Bernoulli variable, so $\Bbb E(X_i)=P[X_i=1]$ for each $i$. Moreover, this quantity is independent of $i$.

So, all you have left  to do is to find the probability that a particular bin  has two or more balls (here, I'd calculate the probability of the complement of this event and subtract from 1).

Comment: Hi David! nice solution, I have asked for a similar problem, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382115/probability-that-at-least-n-cards-will-go-into-a-bucket if you can take a look thanks a lot +1 !

Answer (score 4):

For a particular bin the probability it has more than one ball is $1$ minus the probability it has no balls or one ball, i.e. $$1-\frac{(n-1)^m}{n^m} - \frac{m(n-1)^{m-1}}{n^m}.$$

The expected number of bins with more than one ball is $n$ times this, i.e. something like $$\frac{n^m-(n+m-1)(n-1)^{m-1}}{n^{m-1}}.$$

Comment: So, `expected number of bins` for any case would be `n * probability of particular bin` ??

Comment: @John Yes, by [Linearity of Expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity). See David Mitra's answer for more.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at this [Related Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26528/m-balls-n-boxes-probability-problem)

As the suggested answer in that related problem states, credit to user Henry.

> This answer treats the balls and boxes as distinguishable so each
>   pattern is of equal probability.  I doubt there is a practical
>   experiment to test this which does not also have them distinguishable.
>
> The number of ways of putting $m$ balls in $n$ boxes is $n^m$ since
>   each ball can go in any of the boxes.
>
> The calculation for the number of ways of putting $m$ balls in $n$
>   boxes with each box having at least one ball is more complicated. 
>   Let's call it $A(m,n)$.  If, when deciding what to do with the last
>   ball, all the other boxes are full, then it can go in any of the $n$
>   boxes; if however one of the $n$ boxes is empty and the others full
>   then it must go in the empty one.  So  $$A(m,n) = n A(m-1,n) + n A(m-1,n-1)$$ and clearly $A(m,1) = 1$ (there is only one way with one
>   box) and  $A(m,n) = 0$ for $m \le n$.   $A(n,n)=n!$ as one would
>   expect.
>
> So the probability that all the boxes have at least one ball is  $$ \frac{n! \, S_2 (m,n)}{n^m}.$$
>
> For example, with 3 balls and 2 boxes, this gives $\frac{2 \times 3}{8} = 3/4$.

Comment: I made some changes, for example to change *nm* into $n^m$

Comment: Thanks. I saw that I needed to clean up the formatting, but I had to leave for dinner.