# Expectation time for at least 2 balls in each bin

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Given $N$ bins and an unlimited number of balls, to be assigned one ball per time unit to a
uniformly random bin.  What is the expected time to achieve at least 2 balls in every bin?

From a previous question 
[Probability that all bins contain strictly more than one ball?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253308/probability-that-all-bins-contain-strictly-more-than-one-ball)
we know the probability of failure (of at least one bit fewer than two balls) at time interval $t$ is given by
$$
F(t) = 1 - \frac{N!}{N^t} \sum_i (-1)^i \binom{t}{t-i} \left\{ t-i \atop N - i \right\}
$$
(where the braces are expressing a Stirling number of the second kind).
And much easier reasoning gives the expected time to first success (all bins having two or more balls) as 
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\sum_t t \left[ (1-F(t)) - (1-F(t-1)) \right] \\
= \left[  (1-F(1)) - (1-F(0)) \right] +2\left[  (1-F(2)) - (1-F(1)) \right] + \ldots \\
= F(0) - F(1) + 2F(1) -2F(2)  + 3F(2) -3F(3) +\ldots \\
= \sum_t \left( 1 - \frac{N!}{N^t} \sum_i (-1)^i \binom{t}{t-i} \left\{ t-i \atop N - i \right\} \right)
\end{array}
$$
But it is sometimes easier to get a simpler expression for an expectation value than to express the underlying distribution cleanly, so I am hopeful that this answer can be simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected number of tosses required to put at least 2 balls in each bin is 
$$\mathbb{E}(T)=\int_0^\infty 1-[1-(1+t/N)\exp(-t/N)]^N\,dt.$$
This can be proved by embedding your problem into a Poisson process.

---

**Reference:** Newman, Donald J.; Shepp, Lawrence (1960), "The double dixie cup problem", American Mathematical Monthly 67: 58–61.

Comment: Very good, this is the sort of improvement I was looking for.

Comment: The substitution $x=t/N$ yields the slightly simpler form

$$
\mathbb E(T)=N\int_0^\infty\left[1-\left[1-(1+x)\mathrm e^{-x}\right]^N\right]\,\mathrm dt\;.
$$