# Average number of aggregations in the dataset

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am dealing with numerical codes / sensible data. Part of the data is being blacked because of security reasons.

To simplify the problem, imagine a code of 4 digits [_ _ _ _], e.g. [1 4 3 9] etc., where the first two digits are being blacked, such that they can't be  recovered anymore.

Example: I am seeing the code [* * 5 4], that might represent any of the 100 different possibilities, i.e. [1 2 5 4], [7 4 5 4], [2 2 5 4] etc. The blackening introduces aggregations into the data, e.g. the 2 codes [7 4 5 4], [2 2 5 4] are being aggregated into one [* * 5 4].

Assuming a random distribution of the digits 0-9 over all 4 places and having a set of k = 60 distinct samples of the form [**__], I would like to tell the average number of aggregations in this data.

Edit: As one aggregation I am considering two or more 4-digit codes [_ _ _ _] that have been aggregated into one 2-digit code[* * _ _].

Comment: What exaxtly is "the average number of any duplicates"? What does "any" mean here? If two truncated codes are the same, is that one or two duplicates? If three are the same, is that one, two or three duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is equivalent to the following one:

Let us fill randomly $n$ bins with $m$ balls and ask what is the probability that exactly $k$ bins are filled with at least 2 balls.

The solution of the problem for $k=n$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/253356), where also a formula for computing the number of ways to partition a set of $m$ objects into $k$ subsets so that each subset contains at least 2 objects (aka [2-associated Stirling number of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Associated_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)) is given:
$$S_2(m,k)=\sum_i (-1)^i \binom{m}{m-i} { m-i \brace k - i},\tag1$$
where
$$
{ m \brace k}\equiv S_1(m,k)
$$
are the "usual" Stirling number of second kind.

In our problem along with the bins containing at least 2 balls there are additionally $n-k$ bins containing 0 or 1 ball. Taking this into account the overall number of ways to have exactly $k$ bins with 2 or more balls is:
$$
N_k(n,m)=n!\sum_{l=0}^{n-k}\binom ml\frac{S_2(m-l,k)}{(n-k-l)!}\tag2
$$
where the factor $\dfrac{n!}{(n-k-l)!}$ counts the number of all possible permutations of the bins with account for the fact that empty bins are indistinguishable, and the factor $\binom ml$ counts the number of ways to choose $l$ balls going to bins filled with one ball.

Finally the probability to have $k$ "aggregations" and the expected value of the "aggregations" are given by
$$
p_k(n,m)=\frac{N_k(n,m)}{n^m},\quad \bar{k}(n,m)=\sum_k k p_k(n,m),
$$
respectively.

For your example one obtains:
$$\bar{k}(100,60)\approx12.1233.$$