# Number of urns with more than K balls inside

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

I have a probability problem that I have simplified down to the following:

Given M balls that are thrown randomly (uniformly) into N urns, what is the expected number of urns that have more than K balls inside?

Comment: Equally, so each urn has a 1/N probability

Comment: Try the method in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119076/how-can-i-solve-bins-and-balls-problems

Answer (score 2):

Extending the method given by user Henry in [119076](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119076/how-can-i-solve-bins-and-balls-problems), the probability that each urn has more than $K$ balls inside is

$1-\sum_{i=0}^{K}\frac{M^{i}(N-1)^{M-i}}{N^{M}}$

which means that the number of bins that have more than K balls inside would be $N$ times the probability for a single urn, or

$N(1-\sum_{i=0}^{K}\frac{M^{i}(N-1)^{M-i}}{N^{M}})$

Basically, you calculate the probability that an urn has of having 0, 1, 2, ... K balls inside, and subtract that probability from 1.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I believe the inside of the sum should be a term from the binomial distribution. What you have seems to work for the first 2 values of i but not afterwards.

Comment: +1. GREAT elaboration. I browsed your profile and noticed you "followed" my Materials Modeling stack exchange site proposal but didn't yet click "commit". Would you mind committing now? We have worked really hard for this and need 25 more people with 200 rep to commit, otherwise they won't launch our site. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MTRlZjUyNGY3MGY4ZWY5ZWZkZGVlNmY0NzY5ZjEzN2NjMjNlZTIwMjU0MWU0MDRjNjM2YjIxZmUxNGVhMWZlMHGM23pUo7y5cQ0jl0rBbYtJLWEPnIuIsvgjQSnSfyMm0

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the combinatorial class of  sets with size more than $K$
marked we find

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SEQ}_{=N}(\textsc{SET}_{\le K}(\mathcal{Z})
+\mathcal{U} \times \textsc{SET}_{\gt K}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

and build the generating function

$$G(z, u) = 
\left(u \exp(z) + (1-u) \sum_{q=0}^K \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)^N.$$

The expectation is then given by

$$\frac{1}{N^M} M! [z^M] 
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u) \right|_{u=1}
\\ = \frac{1}{N^{M-1}} M! [z^M] 
\left. 
\left(u \exp(z) + 
(1-u) \sum_{q=0}^K \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)^{N-1} 
\left(\exp(z) - \sum_{q=0}^K \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)
\right|_{u=1}
\\ = \frac{1}{N^{M-1}} M! [z^M] 
\exp((N-1)z)
\left(\exp(z) - \sum_{q=0}^K \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{N^{M-1}} M! [z^M] 
\left(\exp(Nz) - \exp((N-1)z) \sum_{q=0}^K \frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$

Simplifying,

$$N - \frac{1}{N^{M-1}} M! [z^M] 
\sum_{q=0}^K  \frac{z^q}{q!} \exp((N-1)z)
\\ = N - \frac{1}{N^{M-1}} M!
\sum_{q=0}^K [z^{M-q}] \frac{1}{q!} \exp((N-1)z).$$

Here we  may suppose that $M\gt  K$ because we get  zero by inspection
otherwise.  We thus have

$$N - \frac{1}{N^{M-1}} M!
\sum_{q=0}^K  \frac{1}{q!} \frac{(N-1)^{M-q}}{(M-q)!}$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
N - \frac{1}{N^{M-1}}
\sum_{q=0}^K {M\choose q} (N-1)^{M-q}.}$$

We can verify this formula by enumeration, which is
shown below.

```
with(combinat);

ENUMX :=
proc(N, M, K)
    option remember;
    local res, part, psize, mset, adm;

    res := 0;

    part := firstpart(M);

    while type(part, `list`) do
        psize := nops(part);
        mset := convert(part, `multiset`);

        adm :=
        nops(select(ent -> ent > K, part));

        res := res + adm * binomial(N, psize) *
        M!/mul(p!, p in part) *
        psize!/mul(p[2]!, p in mset);

        part := nextpart(part);
    od;

    res/N^M;
end;

X := (N, M, K)
-> N - 1/N^(M-1)
*add(binomial(M,q)*(N-1)^(M-q), q=0..K);
```

Comment: could please expand the starting points about sets considered, thanks

Comment: This is from page 100, II.2. "Admissible labelled constructions" of *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet & Sedgewick, table is on page 104. Distributing balls into $N$ urns is the same as partitioning the $M$ balls into $N$ sets, possibly empty.